# CQ5 - Dialog Participant Chooser step does not open a dialog?

Tags: workflow, aem

I'd love to extend workflows and give a user the opportunity to select "stuff" on custom workflow processes. As far as i understood, using the Dialog Participant Chooser is a workflow step implementation, which can be used to open PopUps.

So, to test the functionality, i'm assigning a simple dialog (the dialog implemented in this tutorial http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/workflows/wf-extending.html) to the Dialog Participant Chooser, but nothing happens.

What am i missing?

- EDIT#1: it does open a dialog, but the one which allows to step further to the next workflow step ...
- EDIT#2: apparently the Dialog Participant Step doesn't care at all, if a dialog is set or not.
- EDIT#3: apparently it just doesn't work when started from the sidekick ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in the sidekick. Adobe provides hotfixes via package share which solve the issue.

Comment: An anonymous user asked ([via an edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5622326)) if you could please provide the hotfix number or link for future reference.

Comment: I'd love to, but I moved forward and I'm not active in that project anymore. I don't have any access to the old sources, sorry.